# Smali change iget-wide to const value

Tags: android, smali

I have this code (original):

```
.method public final component1()J
.registers 3

iget-wide v0, p0, Lio/wondrous/sns/data/model/levels/UserLevel;->totalPoints:J

return-wide v0
.end method
```

I need to return static value, like:

```
const v0, 500000
```

but it construction doesnt work.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't now how something is written in smali you can always build a simple app that contains the code you need, compile it to DEX/APK and then decompile it to smali to see what smali commands to be used. In yor case I would assume youmay get an `const/16 ..`  or `const-wide/32 ...` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
const-wide v0 , 0x500000
```

Or if the 500000 is the decimal then you have to convert it into hex which is **7A120**. Then use this:

```
const-wide v0, 0x7A120
```

The final code will look like:

```
.method public final component1()J
.registers 3

iget-wide v0, p0, Lio/wondrous/sns/data/model/levels/UserLevel;->totalPoints:J

const-wide v0, 0x7A120
.end method
```